# How to email csv file to Owners group using powershell

Tags: powershell, email, groups, export, csv

I have a script that exports data to a csv file listed below:

```
    $url = "http://portal.contoso.com"
$site = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite($url)
$web = $site.OpenWeb()
$list = $web.Lists

function Get-DocInventory() {   

                $web = Get-SPWeb "http://portal.contoso.com"

                    foreach ($list in $web.Lists) {

                        if ($list.BaseType -eq "DocumentLibrary") {

                         $dList = [Microsoft.Sharepoint.SPDocumentLibrary]$list
                         $items = $dList.Items
                         $files = $dList.CheckedOutFiles

                        foreach($file in $files){

                           foreach($item in $items){

                                if($item["Checked Out To"] -ne $null){

                             $wuse = $file.DirName.Substring($web.ServerRelativeUrl.Length)                          
                             $modifiedTime = $web.RegionalSettings.TimeZone
                             $data = @{
                                "Version" = $item["Version"]
                                "library" = $wuse
                                "URL" = $web.Url + ('/') + $item.Url
                                "Title" = $file.LeafName
                                "CheckedOut By" = $file.CheckedOutBy.Name
                                "Time last Modified" = $modifiedTime.UTCToLocalTime($file.TimeLastModified)

                            }
                           }

                              New-Object PSObject -Property $data

                            }
                          }                        
                       }
                    }
                    $web.Dispose();
                }
                $site.Dispose()

        }


Get-DocInventory | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Path D:\Docinventory.csv
```

I need help to add a Powershell script to email the csv file to the Owners Group. Could someone please assist?

Comment: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849925.aspx

Comment: @Eric Alexander thanks for the link I have never done an email script before but could you give me an example to go off of and where specifically on my script to I incorporate that? Please advise.